# OOP: Share an instance of class (Hardware Port) with multiple instances of another class (Filter)

Tags: python, oop

I have a program (user interface) to collect data from  5 different nodes and performs filtering (moving average, winsormean, mode and many other filters) over the received data. The entire program is designed using 3 classes

- Class #1 : `SerialComm` class provide the read and write methods to the
  ONLY one serial port to which all the nodes are physically connected.
- Class #2 : `StatusBar` class provide updating the status bar on the user
  interface ( error messages , acknowledgment to user action of key
  press).
- Class #3 : `Node` class holds the data for each of the 5 nodes , the
  data collected over serial interface is post processed using various
  filtering techniques.

The serial port can have one instance but each of the node instance needs to use this instance to `get_data()`. Similarly `StatusBar` is also only one and currently I'm passing the instance of `SerialComm` and `StatusBar` to each instance of the 5 nodes, shown below.

**I do not like this approach of passing the instances to each object, is there a better way of handling this?**

```
class StatusBar:

   def __init__(self):
      self.status_message = 'none'

   def get_status_msg(self):
      return self.status_message

   def update_status_msg(self, msg):
      self.status_message = msg


class SerialComm:
   def __init__(self, portnum, obj_statusbar, baud=19200):

     # More code follows

     self._portNumber = portnum
     self.statusMsg = obj_statusbar

     try:
        self._portInstance = serial.Serial(self._portNumber,baud, timeout=0.05)
     except IOError, e:
        print e

   def write_bytes(self,len):
     # Write method
   def read_bytes(self,len):
     # read method

class Node:
   def __init__(self,obj_statusbar, obj_comm, n_address, n_location=0, ref_rssi=-50,
                n_color=(255,255,0)):
     self._address= n_address
     self._location=n_location
     self._status_bar =obj_statusbar
     self._comm_port = obj_comm

   def read_sensor(self):          
        if(  self._comm_port.read_bytes(10) != "112233445566778899AA"):
               self._status_bar.update_status_msg(" Data out of boundary")  
     ...
     # More code follows
status_bar = StatusBar()
comm_interface = SerialComm('COM4', status_bar, 19200)

Node_1 = Node(status_bar,comm_interface,0x9,Point(0, 0),-57,RED)
Node_2 = Node(status_bar,comm_interface,0xA,Point(2, 0),-57,GREEN)
Node_3 = Node(status_bar,comm_interface,0xB,Point(1, 2),-57,BLUE)
Node_4 = Node(status_bar,comm_interface,0xC,Point(1, 3),-57,ORANGE)
Node_5 = Node(status_bar,comm_interface,0xD,Point(1, 0),-57,BPINK)
```

Comment: use default arguments? use class attributes?

Comment: Why don't you like this approach of passing instances? Define "better".

Comment: I do not like this for the simple reason that  i have to repeat  passing of the same objects ( 'SerialComm' and 'StatusBar') to every instance of class 'Node'

Answer (score 1):

This approach is fine. The whole point of a constructor is that you have to provide it with the minimum number of arguments so that it can function after instantiation. If your node relies on a statusbar instance then you should pass it to every node.

This gives you the flexibility to have multiple Nodes, StatusBars and SerialComm objects in different relationships. This is especially important for mocking and unit testing. Do NOT be tempted into using some kind of global hack like using singletons or static variables as singletons. Those quickly become very difficult to test.